# How do you get the pop box so you can identify where to put documents in a library that is made of views in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

My library is created with views. I have a category and a subcategory. When I enter the library and click on the new I can not tell where to place my documents.  The usual pop-up box does not appear?  Is there a setting I must now do differently on SharePoint Online as compared to SharePoint 2010?  Is there a possibility something was missing from the installation of SharePoint Online?

I have 4 categories: Venus, Mars, Mercury, Saturn. 
Each of these can have 2 subcategories: Demo, Meeting Minutes

When I go to upload the document, I should have a pop-up box that show "What category do I want to place my document in? A dropdown box should be shown for me to chose Venus, Mars, Mercury or Saturn.  Also shown on this pop-up box a drop down list stating Demo or Meeting minutes.  If I chose Venus and Subcategory Meeting Minutes, my document should be placed in Meeting Minutes under Venus. The screen should show "Venus(1)" When I click on Venus(1) the click on Meeting Minutes, I then should see my document.

Comment: can you share some screen shot to show what you are seeing and what you expect?

Comment: can you please upload screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using modern experience in SharePoint Online. They provide same functions but display differently.

In SharePoint Server 2010, we click **Add document** button and call the *Upload Document* window. In SharePoint Online, we click `Upload > Files` to add an existing document to the document library.

If you click **New**, you can create a new/blank word document using *Word Online*.

[image]

Some documents that might be helpful:

[Upload a folder or files to a document library.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/upload-a-folder-or-files-to-a-document-library-eb18fcba-c953-4d45-8d90-8da66edeacdb)

[Change the default list and library experience.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/change-default-list-and-library-experience)